# Hide row in view if any field is empty

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a **Drupal 7 view** that uses **fields** as display type.

There are three fields, and I don't want to show the row if any one field is empty.

Currently, I am adding a filter for each of the three fields to achieve this. meaning if I have 20 fields, I would have to go for 20 filters.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

**P.S.** I can do this by overriding the row style output template file, and then add some custom php code. But I want to know is there an easier way using the views administration interface.

Comment: template is the easiest way I can think of

Answer (score 0):

When you select 'Fields' under 'Show' in View, in 'settings' you can check "Hide empty fields" option.

Cheers!!!

Comment: It does not hide an entire row if only one field is empty

Comment: In that case select a field which will decide hide entire row if field is empty. In that field override the output add all fields keep all other fields exclude from display.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition on view filter. If image field is empty then row will not display.